# Projection from high dimension to lower, for visualization

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, rotations, projective-geometry

I want to project high dimensional data points onto 2D screen coordinates, for visualization purposes.  I want to be able to control the angles of projection manually (eg, with the mouse).  I have succeeded to code this for $3D \rightarrow 2D$, which is commonly found in math software for 3D scatter plots.  But I don't know the general formula for a rotation in $\mathbb{R}^n$, or projecting at an angle to $\mathbb{R}^2$.  I guess for each extra dimension there is one more degree of freedom (ie, an angle that can be adjusted).

I failed to find a general formula for rotations in $\mathbb{R}^n$;  even the 4D case is rather complicated with 6 parameters (I don't understand why it's 6 instead of 4).

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Comment: This is a good question! I think this link might be of interest https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation (though the result doesn't hold for a general $\Bbb R^n$).

Comment: Even if you can project it, can you visualize it? The mouse can control only 2 dimension per button so you can use many scroll bar, but by my experience with multidimensional magic cubes, the number of parameter is of order $n^2 $.

Comment: Exactly you need $n(n-1)\over2 $ parameters. The reason is: If you have to determine a rotation of $\mathbb R^n$ then you need to determine the rotation of $\mathbb S^{n-1} $. First you find a point on it (n-1 parameters), rotate a fixed point to that, then rotate around that point (equal to rotate $\mathbb S^{n-2} $). The problem remain to be parameterize a point on $\mathbb S^n$ as n parameter.

Comment: But we're talking about rotating the (fixed) axes.  With each extra dimension, there is just 1 more axis, and we try to rotate around it.

Comment: @Yan rotating around an axis is peculiar to three dimensions. It's more complicated in higher dimensions.

Comment: In 4D, you cannot rotate around an axis, but you rotate around a 2-plane. Similarly in 2D you rotate around a point. A general formula would be easy. In $\mathbb R^n$ you can use "hyper-cylinder" rotation (pick two axes $x_1$ and $x_2$, rotate all points around them while keep the remaining coordinate unchanged) to construct any rotation (recursively in $\mathbb R^n$).

Comment: To construct one in $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, you can use the following procedure: 1. Assume the axes are $x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_n$, then (recursively) use $n(n-1)\over2$ parameters rotate around axes $x_0,x_1,x_2,...,x_{n-1}$, while keep the last coordinate unchanged. 2. The point $(0,0,...,0,1)$ is in the same position, so if you can move it to any point in $\mathbb S^n$, then you achived free rotation. Use $n$ parameters $p_0,p_1,...$, then rotate $x_n\to x_0$ by ${p_0}^\circ$, $x_n\to x_1$ by ${p_1}^\circ$, etc. until you used all parameters. This is similar to Euler rotation so it has gimbal lock.

Comment: @user202729: per your 1st comment, in any dimension, I can always pick 2 axes and rotate around them (because a circle of dim 1 is on the 2-plane defined by the axes).  So then I have free rotations (no proof yet)?  This seems easier to do with a mouse.

Comment: What's your data? Are all dimensions really the same, so that it makes sense to concentrate on rotations only, as opposed to general linear transformations which would incluse shearing etc.? This is not what you asked for, but in case of statistical data I'd have a look at primary component analysis (PCA) which can nicely project high-dimensional stuff to 2D in a meaningful way. Not a configurable way, though, and not a pure rotation either. You could consider taking the first 3 components and allow user 3D rotations of these, which should still be fairly intuitive.

Comment: Yes, I knew of PCA, but my intent is precisely to look at the data in "raw" form.  I am studying dynamics of neural networks in high-dim space.  I want to look at state trajectories, chaos, etc.